# Supporting multiple JSON content types in Grape

Tags: ruby, json, api, ruby-grape

I’ve been using Grape to write an Evernote-like API, and have been using Collection+JSON (MIME type "application/vnd.collection+json"). I now want to also support JSON API (mime type "application/vnd.api+json").

(The reason I want to do this is so it will be easier to write an Ember client, since Ember Data has support for JSON API built in. It might make more sense to write client-side JavaScript to solve my problem, but I’m stronger in Ruby than JavaScript.)

My goal is to have the server support either format, and choose which one based on the Accept header. Is this a reasonable thing to do, or does it not make sense to have multiple JSON types? It appears that Grape doesn’t support this. If I just have the wrong idea, then the code below is probably not relevant to that answer.

Here are some relevant pieces of my server code:

```
class NotesServer < Grape::API
  content_type :json, ‘application/json’


  content_type :json_api, 'application/vnd.api+json'
  formatter :json_api, lambda { |object, env| object.to_json_api }

  content_type :collection_json, 'application/vnd.collection+json'
  formatter :collection_json, lambda { |object, env| object.to_collection_json }

  resource :notes do
    desc 'Get a note.'

    params do
      requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'Note ID.'
    end

    route_param :id do
      get do
        NoteRepresenter.new Note.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
end
```

…where NoteRepresenter defines both to_json_api and to_collection_json.

The idea is to use the same Representer in either case, but to call the appropriate method depending on the Accept header.

When I run curl against this with any Accept header, the response has Content-Type: application/json, and “to_json” is called on the representer. If I leave out the `content_type :json, ‘application/json’` line, I get a 406 Not Acceptable response every time.

I figured out that in the Grape library, in lib/grape/middleware/formatter.rb, the "format" of a request is considered JSON for any of these MIME types, since the vnd.collection+ or vnd.api+ parts are parsed out of the header. So my question is, is this a matter of Grape not supporting what I’m trying to do, or am I trying to do something that makes no sense?

Comment: Why the `application/vnd.api+json` type vs. `application/json`?

Comment: I don't know Grape at all, but supporting multiple content types based on the Accept header is *definitely* the HTTP/standard way to do this, and a reasonable approach/goal as well.

Comment: @tadman I'm trying to use the standard documented here: http://jsonapi.org/ , and similarly for Collection+JSON here: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/

Comment: You may need to stick in a Rack handler that maps these to regular JSON, or decodes them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable way to do this that I’mr reasonably happy with, but I don’t think it totally aligns with how Grape expects you to do things.

I created a custom formatter called JsonFormatter, so my server code looks like this:

```
class NotesServer < Grape::API
  formatter :json, JsonFormatter
  # …
end
```

And the formatter itself:

```
module JsonFormatter
  def self.call(object, env)
    case env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    when 'application/vnd.api+json'
      object.to_json_api
    when 'application/vnd.collection+json'
      object.to_collection_json
    else
      object.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

So now either to_json_api or to_collection_api (or to_json) will be called on the presenter object, depending on the Accept header. One issue I haven’t solved yet is that the Content-Type is set to application/json in all cases.